# SQL get records from two columns in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records from two columns in such a way that the output contains 1 record from 1st col then 1st record from 2nd col.

the senario is like this

```
ColA     ColB
1         a
2         b
3         c

Output
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

Comment: Have you tried [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach without window functions, assuming that `ColA` specifies the ordering for the rows:

```
select output
from ((select cola as output, cola as ordering, 'a' as which
       from table t
      ) union all
      (select colb, cola, 'b'
       from table t
      )
     ) t
order by ordering, which;
```

Note that this will guarantee that the values are interleaved in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.Output FROM
(
   SELECT Output = CAST(ColA AS VARCHAR(10)), 
          RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ColA,ColB)
   FROM TableName 

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT Output = ColB, 
          RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ColA,ColB)
   FROM TableName 
) X
ORDER BY x.RN
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f3cf/4/0

Comment: Thanks Tim But it was close but i didnt got the exact result.
The result set I got was like
1  
a  
b  
2  
3  
c  
d  
4  

Whereas what i wanted was like
1
a  
2  
b  
3  
c